# Fragment in ActionBar Tab can't access activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have followed the guide at developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/action.bar.html on implementing tabs in the action bar.

In my main activity I add three tabs:

```
public class ToDoActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Task List")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<TaskListFragment>(
                    this, "task list", TaskListFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Pie Chart")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<TaskPieChartFragment>(
                    this, "pie chart", TaskPieChartFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Task Map")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<TaskMapFragment>(
                    this, "task map", TaskMapFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
    }
}
```

The fragment of the first tab executes just fine. It can find views and access the activity. Clicking on the second tab in the navigation shows the fragment (as intended), but no life cycle functions of that fragment are executed (onActivityCreated(), onStart(), onResume(), etc.). Also every call to getActivity() from that fragment returns a null object.

```
public class TaskPieChartFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task_pie_chart, container, false);
    }

    public void updatePieChart() {
        TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.some_text);
        textView.setText("something something");
    }
}
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/some_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The updatePieChart() function is called from within the TabListener:

```
public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity,  mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
        try {
            TaskPieChartFragment pieChartFragment = (TaskPieChartFragment) mFragment;
            pieChartFragment.updatePieChart();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // not the fragment we were looking for
        }
    }

}
```

Whenever I select the tab with the TaskPieChartFragment I get a NullPointerException originating at the first line in updatePieChart(). Why is it that this second fragment behaves completely different from the first one and I don't seem to be able to get a reference to the activity?

PS

I also tried passing on the activity saved in TabListener. Then the NullPointerException does not originate on the first line in updatePieChart(), but the second, so the activity can't find the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason it's crashing it's because the `FragmentTransaction` is not even completed yet.

the method `getActivity()` only returns the activity between the fragment callbacks `onAttach()` and `onDetach()` and that will only happen after the transaction `ft` is completed and the Framework goes through all the callbacks.

You probably should update your pie-chart during `onResume()` or some other of the Fragment life-cycle callbacks.

**edit:**

re-reading through the code, at the moment you're calling `updatePieChart()` the views have not been created yet. So there's that too.

As a general rule the views of a fragment should be updated inside the actual fragment.

probably something like that:

public class TaskPieChartFragment extends Fragment {

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task_pie_chart, container, false);
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    updatePieChart();
}

private void updatePieChart() {
    TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.some_text);
    textView.setText("something something");
}
```

}

the idea for that is that fragments should be self-contained entities and not rely on the activity calling them for updating.

Answer (score 0):

The Activity doesn't own the view so it's not surprising that it can't find it.  Replace `getActivity()` with `getView()` and you should be good to go.  `getView()` gives you the root view of this Fragment and that should be able to find the view you're looking for because it is one of the view's ancestors.  You can only find a view with one of its ancestors because `findViewWithId()` looks through all the children recursively to find the view.